# In SAS, how do you create a certain number of records where the primary outcome does not occur based on the value of another variable?

Tags: sas, categorical-data

I am examining the effect of passing vs running plays on injuries across a few football seasons. The way the data was collected, all injuries were recorded as well as information about the play in which the injury occurred (ie position, quarter, play type), game info (ie weather conditions, playing surface, etc), and team info (ie number of pass vs run plays in the game).

I would like to use one play as the primary exposure with the outcome as injury vs no injury with analysis using logistic regression, but to do so I would need to create all the records with no injury. There is a range from 0 to around 6-7 injuries in a game for a team, and the total passing and running plays are recorded so I would need to find a way to add X (total passing plays minus injuries on passing plays) and Y (total running plays - injuries on running plays) records that share all the details for that particular game but have no injury as the outcome. I imagine there is a way in proc sql to do this, but I could not find it online. How would I go about coding this?

I have attached an example of the relevant data. An example of what I would need to do is for game 1 add 30 records for passing plays and 38 records for running plays with outcome of no injury and otherwise the same data (team A, dry weather, game plays).

[image: Sample data image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `freq` statement to prevent having to de-aggregate it.

> The FREQ statement identifies a variable that contains the frequency
> of occurrence of each observation. PROC LOGISTIC treats each
> observation as if it appears n times, where n is the value of the FREQ
> variable for the observation. If it is not an integer, the frequency
> value is truncated to an integer.

[SAS Documentation](https://go.documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=statug&docsetTarget=statug_logistic_syntax18.htm&docsetVersion=14.2&locale=en)

De-aggregating the data would require the data step and a `do` loop. It's not recommended to do this.

Comment: Could you please give an example of coding where PROC FREQ would accomplish what I would want it to?